# Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError

Tags: java, logging, ant, jar

From SLF4J page I understood this

> The purpose of slf4j-log4j12 module is to delegate or redirect calls made to an SLF4J logger to log4j. The purpose of the log4j-over-slf4j module is to redirect calls made to a log4j logger to SLF4J. If SLF4J is bound withslf4j-log4j12.jar and log4j-over-slf4j.jar is also present on the class path, a StackOverflowError will inevitably occur immediately after the first invocation of an SLF4J or a log4j logger.

My question is how to prevent this error if there are two libraries which I am using contain these jars?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar error, this how I resolved it using NetBeans IDE 8.2:

1. Access Project explorer view on netbeans IDE. Proceed to your project under **Dependencies** hover the cursor over the *log4j-over-slf4j.jar* to view the which which dependencies have indirectly imported as shown below.

[image]

2. Right click an import jar file and select **Exclude Dependency**

[image]

3. To confirm, open your pom.xml file you will notice the *exclusion* element as below.
   [image]
4. Initiate maven clean install and run your project. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to prevent that error besides getting rid of one of the jars.